# Suppose $R$ is a total order on a set $A$. Prove that every finite, nonempty set $B \subseteq A$ has an $R$-smallest element.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Proposition:

> Suppose $R$ is a total order on a set $A$. Prove that every finite,
>   nonempty set $B \subseteq A$ has an $R$-smallest element.

My attempt:

Cardinality of the set, say $A$, will be denoted as $|A|$.

By induction.

**Base case:**

Take $B = \{b\}$ such that $b \in A$. $b$ is the $R$-smallest element of $B$.

**Induction step:**

Suppose for all sets with $n$ elements, there will be smallest element.

Consider arbitrary set $B \subseteq A$ such that $|B| = n + 1$.

Take arbitrary $b \in B$.

Let $B' = B \setminus \{b\}$. By inductive hypothesis, $B'$ has $R$-smallest element. Let's call it $c$.

Now consider set $B$.

Suppose $cRb$. Then $c$ is the smallest element of $B$.

Suppose $bRc$. Take arbitrary $y \in B$. We know that $cRy$. By transitivity we have $bRy$. $y$ was arbitrary, hence $b$ is the smallest element of $B$.

Suppose that $\lnot bRc$ and $\lnot cRb$. This is impossible, because $R$ is a total order on $A$.

Therefore, either $c$ or $b$ will be the smallest element of $B$.

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s a pretty good solid proof.